# Percentage Monthly Data

Tags: python, pandas

I've got some volume data on a daily level with a type column.

```
         Day       Type    Volume
0        20230101  0       -23336.289
1        20230101  1       2930009.848
2        20230101  2       -2906673.559
3        20230102  0       7377.021
4        20230102  1       2892521.704
5        20230102  2       -2899898.724
```

I'd like to create a column, maybe `mon_pct`, that uses the volumes from each day of type 0 and divides them by the monthly sum of volumes of type 1. For example, (-23336.289 / (Jan Sum Type 1)) * 100. Only rows of type 0 would get a resultant value.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
m = df['Type'].eq(0)

df.loc[m, 'mon_pct'] = (df['Volume']
 .where(df['Type'].eq(1))
 .groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['Day']).dt .to_period('M'))
 .transform('sum')[m]
 .rdiv(df['Volume']).mul(100)
)
```

Output:

```
        Day  Type       Volume   mon_pct
0  20230101     0   -23336.289 -0.400793
1  20230101     1  2930009.848       NaN
2  20230101     2 -2906673.559       NaN
3  20230102     0     7377.021  0.126698
4  20230102     1  2892521.704       NaN
5  20230102     2 -2899898.724       NaN
```

Comment: This is great. It's succinct, easy to read, and flexible. This is a really cool solution, and I definitely feel like I've learned something new. Thanks.

Comment: @John glad it was helpful, happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the sum of volume for Type 1 entires:

```
type_1_sum = df["Volume"][df["Type"] == 1].sum()
```

Create a new DF with mon_pct column consisting of Type 0 entries

```
df_type_0 = df[df['Type'] == 0].copy()
df_type_0["mon_pct"] = (df["Volume"]/type_1_sum)*100
```

Merge the new df to old one

```
df = df.merge(df_type_0, how='left')
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, which is based on [`pandas.DataFrame.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
(df.assign(
    mon_pct = df['Volume'].where(df['Type'].eq(0))
    .div(
        df.assign(
            Day = pd.to_datetime(df['Day'], format='%Y%m%d'))
        .set_index('Day').loc[lambda x: x['Type'].eq(1)]
        .resample('M')['Volume'].sum().iloc[0])
    .mul(100))
)
```

Output:

```
        Day  Type       Volume   mon_pct
0  20230101     0   -23336.289 -0.400793
1  20230101     1  2930009.848       NaN
2  20230101     2 -2906673.559       NaN
3  20230102     0     7377.021  0.126698
4  20230102     1  2892521.704       NaN
5  20230102     2 -2899898.724       NaN
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
data = {
    'Day': [20230101, 20230101, 20230101, 20230102, 20230102, 20230102],
    'Type': [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2],
    'Volume': [-23336.289, 2930009.848, -2906673.559, 7377.021, 2892521.704, -2899898.724]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert 'Day' to datetime
df['Day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Day'], format='%Y%m%d')

# Calculate the monthly sum of volumes for 'Type 1'
monthly_sum_type1 = df[df['Type'] == 1].groupby(df['Day'].dt.month)['Volume'].sum()

# Create a function to calculate 'mon_pct'
def calculate_mon_pct(row):
    if row['Type'] == 0:
        month = row['Day'].month
        if month in monthly_sum_type1:
            return (row['Volume'] / monthly_sum_type1[month]) * 100
    return None

# Apply the function to create the 'mon_pct' column
df['mon_pct'] = df.apply(calculate_mon_pct, axis=1)

# Print the resulting DataFrame
print(df)
```

!note that you should replace the sample data with your actual dataset.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).